# GridLayout change only one specific element?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have GridLayout 7x7, is it possible to change content only of cell (3,4) and I want to do it dynamically.
Example: I have 7x7 grid of buttons and want to change button on position (3,4) to TextView.

**EDIT:** Also, is it possible to set zero padding around child?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GridView you cant access elements specific by coordinates (3,4).
The elements are numbered like in 2D arrays. So your (3,4) element will have (7*3+4)-1 index. And you can access it by.

```
ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) mGridView.getChildAt(24);
```

**EDIT:** Set padding to zero.

```
gridChild.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Finally :) only padding isn't on 0, still same as before.

Comment: Try getPaddingTop(), getPaddingBottom(), getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingRight(). If they return 0, then for example if your padding to all cells is 20dp, you have to set.
gridChild.setPadding(-20,-20,-20,-20);